# How can I allow lexical variable declarations in my subroutine arguments the way opendir does?

Tags: perl, reference

Some Perl functions allow you to pass lexical variables declared in the argument list:

```
opendir(my $h, '.') or die $!;
```

What exactly is going on here? I can simulate similar behavior using references:

```
sub a {
    my ($ref) = @_;
    $$ref = 100;
}

my $value;
a(\$value);
STDOUT->say($value); # => 100
```

But it doesn't quite work like `opendir`, because I need to wrap the scalar in a reference:

```
a(my $value);
STDOUT->say($value); # => nothing
```

Is it possible to reproduce the behavior of `opendir` here?

Comment: I have no idea what "out parameters" means but I've edited your question to reflect what I think you're trying to ask. Feel free to rollback/edit if I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#DESCRIPTION):

> Any arguments passed in show up in the array `@_`. Therefore, if you called a function with two arguments, those would be stored in `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`. The array `@_` is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters. In particular, if an element `$_[0]` is updated, the corresponding argument is updated (or an error occurs if it is not updatable).

In other words, assignments to elements of `@_` will be made to the actual parameters of the call

```
sub a {
    $_[0] = 100;
}

my $x;
a($x);
print "$x\n"; # => 100
```

Alternatively:

```
sub a {
    my $x = \$_[0];
    $$x = 100;
}

a(my $x);
print "$x\n"; # => 100
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I'm not sure how much value your *Alternatively* gives. It's never specifically guaranteed that `\$_[0]`will be identical to a reference to the calling parameter, but that's mainly because *“aliases”* is never properly defined. I also think it's confusing to pass `my $x` as a parameter, as that could be seen as part of the mechanism; that's why I've separated the two in your first example. It's also probably worth mentioning that `a(99)` will raise an appropriate error because you would be attempting to modify a Perl literal

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that may help. Note that it doesn't make any checks on the open mode and just makes naive guesses. If you need something like this, you then you should really [`use autodie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) on version 10.1 or later of Perl 5

The part relevant to your question is that the line

```
my ($mode, $file) = @_[1,2]
```

pulls the second and third *input* parameters out for local use. The subroutine opens the passed-in file path and mode to open the file using a lexical file handle, and then returns that file handle by assigning to the first parameter with the line

```
$_[0] = $fh;
```

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my_open(my $fh, '<<', 'xyzzy');

sub my_open {

    my ($mode, $file) = @_[1,2]

    my $modestring = $mode =~ />>/ ? 'append' : $mode =~ />/ ? 'write' : 'read';

    open my $fh, $mode, $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for $modestring: $!};

    $_[0] = $fh;
}
```